# Stopping jQuery from doing its thing?

Tags: jquery, function, iteration, fade

I have this code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#box').hide();
$(window).bind('scroll', function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
        $("#box").fadeIn(300);
    }
    else {
    $("#box").fadeOut(300);
    }
});
});
```

So when I scroll down 200px it will make a div appear. When I scroll back up, it will disappear. This is fine, until I do it a lot.

If I scroll up and down like a nutter the div keeps fading in and out even after I stop. This isn't related to just this instance, it's happened a lot in the past and I've always wanted to know how to fix it (by making it stop as soon as I have, without doing it for everytime I scrolled up and down).

Is that possible?

Comment: Yeah good question.  Have wondered that myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.clearQueue() worked much better than .stop()

Answer (score 3):

jQuery has a stop() method - http://api.jquery.com/stop/

This article describes how to use it, seems to be exactly what you're looking for:
http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/01/quick-tip-prevent-animation-queue-buildup

Comment: It works for a while but it seems it can just break easily no matter where I put the stop - eventually it just stops fading in or out completely.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`stop`<sup>docs</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) function

You simply need to call `$('#box').stop(true,true).fadeIn(300);` and `$('#box').stop(true,true).fadeOut(300);` respectively

Answer (score 1):

Try using stop() before more animations are queued:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#box').hide();
    $(window).bind('scroll', function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
            $("#box").stop().fadeIn(300);
        }
        else {
            $("#box").stop().fadeOut(300);
        }
    });
});
```

See the documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 1):

You have to add stop function to your queue like this:
$('#box').stop(true).fadeOut(300);

function stop() description: [see here](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)